# Restart a service, and its dependents remotely in Windows

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell, service

Normally after running Windows updates there are a few servers in our infrastructure that our monitoring software (SolarWinds) shows as having problems.  Normally this is flagged as being the netman service not having started.  to rectify I normally log in to the server and restart the Netman service (and if that hasnt shifted the error the winmgmt and snmp services as well).  I absolutely know there must be a bertter way to do this.

I have looked at powershell but running the following yields no change in the service:

```
Get-Service -ComputerName XFILES -Name netman | Restart-Service -Verbose
```

Even if I add "-Force" to the command all I get is the repsonse of it performing the restart but the service never actually restarts.

I have also looked at psservice but this seems to struggle again with dependancies though it works very well for lone wolf services.  Am I destined to have to write full on script that will enumerate dependent services or am I missing a super simple way of achieving this?

Comment: I'd better look deeper in a rooctause, why the service fails to start.
Check **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\Netman\Parameters** registry key and make sure the entry **ServiceDll REG_EXPAND_SZ %SystemRoot%\System32\netman.dll** exists. If Not, create it

Comment: its more a problem with the monitoring software.  the service has started but for whatever reason our implementation of solarwinds does not see the service as up.  restarting the service and repolling the node in solarwinds clears the warning.  Probably not best practice I agree.  I have double checked though and that reg key does exist.

Comment: Does this happen to only one service? Have you tried to change poll interval for this service?

Comment: It is normally only the netman service that fails to show as being up.  The default polling and timeout are set on the application monitor (300 seconds).  Repolling without restarting the service does not clear the "down" status.

Comment: What about lag value, i.e. time before service turns red in monitoring, have you tried to make it longer and wait for some time to see whether info about service status is propogated?

Comment: Tim, have you tried using the WMI method to restart the service? something like `$Srv = gwmi win32_service | where {$_.name -match "WinRM"};$Srv.StopService();$Srv.StartService()`. I've had issues too with using the cmdlets especially on remote machines but using the WMI methods seem to work okay.

Comment: hadnt tried the wmi but that seems to have worked!  If you put it as an answer below I will accept and up vote.  Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

You could pause before starting the service again:

```
Stop-Service "my service" -Verbose; Start-Sleep -Seconds 30; Start-Service "my service" -Verbose
```